# Android connect to mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, web-services, httprequest

I have the following code that throws a null exception

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://exemple.com/android_webservice/index.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", String.valueOf(l.getLatitude()) ));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lng", String.valueOf(l.getLongitude()) ));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            //I belive exception is thrown somewhere above this

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        String json = reader.readLine();
        JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(json);
        JSONArray finalResult = new JSONArray(tokener);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(map.getApplicationContext(), "Exception here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // Toast is displayed so the exception is this one
    }
```

The webservice it acces is PHP. I use $_REQUEST to get lat. and lng inside the script, I belive this should not be a problem. Also could it be possible that the web server does not accept a mobile phone makeing requests to it ?

Comment: Could it be that you do not acces this method/httpresponse in asynctask or other thread than UI-Thread

Comment: could you pls provide a full logcat

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you do not acces this method/httpresponse in asynctask or other thread than UI-Thread? 
So you getting a nullpointer exception because your reuqest does not work and you are not getting any response from the server?

If so please keep in mind that accessing network from main-thread will cause a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

To avoid this use Asynctask as described here:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

or here
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I put it inside a runnable and also added a check for NetworkOnMainThreadException but still the exception I am getting is of tipe Exception...

Comment: try to mak a break on the response and have a look at it.

Comment: I belive that this line is throwing the exception HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

Comment: yeah so try it in asyncask, it shoud work. did u set the interent permission?